# Radio Button to change form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons each one will toggle different inputs on a form. I've achomplished this using the `onclick()` function that utilizes `hide()` but then this require another function with replicated `.show()` to bring the elements back if the user toggles back and forth. Thought there must be better logic something that is not so redundant, maybe an if toggle value?

Anyways this is what I have:

```
<labe>    
    <input type="radio" name="radioReason" onClick="resetPassShow()"> </input
         <span class="text">Request profile update (i.e. phone#)</span>
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioReason" value="resetPassword" onClick="resetPassRemove;"> </input>
    <span class="text">Reset Password or Unlock My Account</span>
</label>

function resetPassRemove(){
    $("#prodCategoryLabel").hide();
    ....
}

function resetPassShow(){
    $("#prodCategoryLabel").show();
    ....
}
```

Comment: your posted HTML code is messed up. please clean it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JS Fiddle in action: https://jsfiddle.net/dv5xmw9z/1/

**JS**

```
function hideA(x) {
   if (x.checked) {
     document.getElementById("A").style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("B").style.visibility = "visible";
   }
 }

 function hideB(x) {
   if (x.checked) {
     document.getElementById("B").style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("A").style.visibility = "visible";
   }
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" onchange="hideB(this)" name="aorb" checked>A |
<input type="radio" onchange="hideA(this)" name="aorb">B
<div id="A">
  <br/>A's text</div>
<div id="B" style="visibility:hidden">
  <br/>B's text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$( ".target" ).toggle();` function.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/